# como solucionar el error índice fuera de los límites de la matriz en c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola a todos tengo esta funcion que se encarga de recorrerme un dictionary y hacer update en la tabla pertinente, y funciona para casi todos los datos que tiene el dictionary que solo son 76, pero me da este error: índice fuera de los límites de la matriz

Mi codigo aqui:

```
public bool UpdateDataNote(string serverip, string database, string usersql, 
string passwdsql, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
Connection conex = new Connection();
conex.serverip = serverip;
conex.user_sql = usersql;
conex.database_provider = database;
bool answer = false;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(passwdsql))
        {
            conex.password_sql = "";
        }
        else
        {
            conex.password_sql = MdCrypt.DecryptPassword(passwdsql);
        }           
        var query = "";
        string HeaderId = parameters["HeaderId"].ToString();
        using (var cn = conex.Conect())
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> row in parameters)
            {
                var key = row.Key;
                var value = row.Value;
                if (!value.Equals("HeaderId"))
                {
                    var arr = key.Split('-');
                    string TypeComponent = arr[0].ToString();
                    string ControlId = arr[1].ToString();
                    if (TypeComponent.Equals("TIssEdit"))
                    {
                        query = "update MDNOTESBIOPSYCHOSOCIAL set CONTENTS = @Content,CONTENTS_PLAINTEXT=@CONTENTS_PLAINTEXT where ControlID = @ControlId and HEADERID = @HeaderId";
                        var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTENTS_PLAINTEXT", value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ControlId", ControlId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HeaderId", HeaderId);

                        try
                        {
                            ConnectionState state = cn.State;
                            if (state == ConnectionState.Open)
                            {
                                var datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                datareader.Close();
                                answer = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cn.Open();
                                var datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                datareader.Close();
                                answer = true;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                        {
                            cn.Close();
                            answer = false;                                
                            break;                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el error es claro. En algún momento te está llegando una `key` que no contiene un carácter `-`. Esto hace que el `Split` solo devuelva un elemento en el array `arr`, y te falle en esta línea: `string ControlId = arr[1].ToString();`

Revisa bien los datos que te llegan y para evitar la excepción, ponle un control,algo asi:

```
if (key.Contains('-'))
{
    var arr = key.Split('-');
    string TypeComponent = arr[0].ToString();
    string ControlId = arr[1].ToString();
}
else
{
     //gestionar la situación
}
```

Comment: eso pense en algun momento pero debugueando el proyecto y viendo todos los key que se envian todos tienen el - execpto el parametro que viene en HeaderId pero ese si lo controlo en el codigo o sea por esa parte debe funcionar bien, no se que sera

Comment: @RaidelFonseca Si el error está en el código que indicas, es ese seguro. Prueba a poner el código que te he dicho a ver si asi ya no falla. Si no es asi, edita tu pregunta y pega el texto de la excepción y en qué línea se lanza

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda ya encontré el error ciertamente se estaba perdiendo a la hora de hacer el split con la posicion del headerid, que controle esa excepcion, pero me confundi de atributo no era if (!value.Equals("HeaderId")) era if (!key.Equals("HeaderId"))